# How to initialize an array using a for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I was hoping someone could help me. I have a homework problem that says declare an array that can store exactly 7 int values. Show 2 different ways to initialize the cells in the array so that they all contain the value 65. One technique MUST use a loop.

I figured out a way to do it without a loop but can someone show me a way to do it with a loop? 
Thank you!

Comment: a simple google search for `c for loop example` would have given a tons of answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will do :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 7

int main()
{
   int arr[MAX_SIZE];

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) 
       arr[i] = 65;

   // Verify array output :
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
       printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it,

```
const int SIZE = 7; /* <----------- The size. */
int array[SIZE];    /* <----------- How to declare an int array. */
int x;              /* <----------- The loop counter. */
for(x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) { /* <--- Initialize x. Test (x < SIZE). Increment x. */
    array[x] = 65; /* <------------ Set to 65 */
}
```